# Function assigned to a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scoping

```
def f(x):
    def g():
        x = 'abc'
        print ('x =', x)
    def h():
        z = x
        print ('z =', z)
    x = x + 1
    print ('x =', x)
    h()
    g()
    print ('x =', x)
    return g
x = 3
z = f(x)
z()
```

return value of f() is assigned to variable z when this happens it invokes function f() I understand so far but how does z() directly returns the value returned by f ? Could you explain this briefly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You assign the *returnvalue* of the call of `f()` to `z`.
You do *not* assign `f` to `z`.

So calling `z()` will only execute the returned inner `g` function - not the whole `f`.

On `z = f()` you get the printout of `f` and then `g` as function returned. On consecutive calls to `z()` you execute the inner `g` function directly.

Answer (score 1):

You have effectively created a pointer (in variable z) to the function f(x). Calling z() therefore calls f(x). Because f(x) returns g, z() will also return g, as calling z() executes f(x).

Comment: But why does calling z() ignore all lines in f(x) but return ?